# define custom integer type in swift 2.2

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift2

I'm making a little "adress book" in Swift 2.2 and I wanted to make a custom type for phone numbers (which would always be positive numbers of 10 digits).
Looking around the internet, I came up with this:

```
typealias phoneNumber = 100000000...9999999999
```

but I'm not sure it would work.

How could I do that? Thanks

Comment: Using integers for phone numbers is a bad idea. International phone numbers can have more than 10 digits, and can have leading zeros.

Comment: @MartinR Well, that makes sense....so, could I define the number to be a string with **only digits** in it?

Comment: Bear in mind that you can have non-digits in a number as well; for example + is used as the leading international dialing code number (which is 00 in most countries and 010 in the 'states) and it's usual to allow brackets and dashes in phone numbers as well for convenience. They also have some meanings; for example +44 (0) 1234 means use +44 1234 outside the UK and 01234 inside the UK, so you can't just strip all the letters since 4401234 is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [PhoneNumberKit](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit).

Then it would be as easy as:

```
do {
    let phoneNumber = try PhoneNumber(rawNumber:"+33 6 89 017383")
}
catch {
    print("Generic parser error")
}
```

Comment: I actually saw PhoneNumberKit on GitHub and it's exactly what I need, but I couldn't install it, neither with CocoaPods or Carthage (they both give weird errors), so now I am struggling to find a way to implement it in my project. Do you now how I could do that? I'm using Swift 2.2 on Xcode 7

Comment: @NOVA99 you probably can just download it and add the folder `/PhoneNumberKit` to your project, there should be everything you need (you can check what you really need by opening one of the example projects). But I would try to fix the cocoapods issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class or struct to hold the digits instead, and then have the validation routines for what makes a correct number as part of the initailizer.

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all these are very big numbers, even a 32 bit integer is not enough to store 9999999999, and the compiler will display an error that it overflows.

Maybe you should make a PhoneNumber type and make it IntegerLiteralConvertible to create it like it is a number. As mentioned above, you have to use 64 bit types.

```
public struct PhoneNumber: IntegerLiteralConvertible, CustomStringConvertible      {

    var phoneNumber: UInt64

    public init(integerLiteral value: UInt64) {
        if UInt64(100000000)...UInt64((UInt64(1000000000) * UInt64(10)) - UInt64(1)) ~= value {
            phoneNumber = value
        }
        else {
            fatalError()
        }
    }

    public var description: String {
        return "+\(phoneNumber)"
    }

    public func call() {
        //custom implementation
    }
}
```

You can add any other methods here like "call()". The usage is simple, but you have to explicitly tell the compiler the type.

```
let momsNumber: PhoneNumber = 3630123456
```

One of the downsides is that it may cause a runtime error.